# Applying Python function to all elements to output vector (conversion from R)

Tags: python, r, matplotlib, statistics

I've been trying to convert some code in R to Python to plot a curve, but have encountered several errors mainly related to applying the function `rss` (residual sum of squares) to `Beta2s`, which in the original R code is done via `sapply()`. I've tried using `map()`, but it doesn't run well in Matplotlib cos I get the error that it `does not support generators as input`. I've done `list(map())` and get the error that `'int' object is not iterable`. Would appreciate any help!

Here's the code in R:

```
rss <- function(Beta0,Beta1,Beta2){
  r <- y - (Beta0+Beta1*tt+Beta2*tt^2)
  sum(r^2)
}

Beta2s <- seq(-10,0,len=100)
RSS <- sapply(Beta2s, rss, Beta0=55, Beta1=0)
plot(Beta2s,RSS,Type="l")
```

Here's my attempt in Python:

```
def rss(Beta0, Beta1, Beta2):
    r = y - (Beta0 + Beta1*t + Beta2*t**2)
    return np.sum(r**2)

Beta2s = np.linspace(-10, 0, num = 100)
Beta0 = 55
Beta1 = 0
RSS = rss(Beta2s) #<-----------------Need help here
plt.plot(Beta2s, RSS)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in R:

```
tt <- seq(1,10,length.out=100)
y <- seq(1,10,length.out=100)
Beta0 = 55
Beta1 = 0
Beta2s <- seq(-10,0,len=100)
RSS <- sapply(Beta2s, rss, Beta0=55, Beta1=0)

head(RSS)
[1] 19223571 18806870 18394761 17987243 17584318 17185985
```

In python:

```
Beta2s = np.linspace(-10, 0, num = 100)
Beta0 = 55
Beta1 = 0
y = np.linspace(1,10,100)
t = np.linspace(1,10,100)
```

For plotting you can just use a list comprehension:

```
plt.plot(Beta2s,[rss(Beta0,Beta1,i) for i in Beta2s])
```

Or you vectorize the function:

```
RSS = np.vectorize(rss)(Beta0,Beta1,Beta2s)

RSS[:5]
array([19223570.88655147, 18806869.74602632, 18394760.55678168,
       17987243.31881757, 17584318.03213398])
```

Answer (score 2):

Using map:

```
# Import and initialise the packages required in session: 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Define rss function: rss => function 
def rss(Beta0, Beta1, Beta2):
    r = y - (Beta0 + Beta1*t + Beta2*t**2)
    return np.sum(r**2)

# Generate data: Beta2s => numpy ndarray
Beta2s = np.linspace(-10, 0, num = 100)

# Store constant values as scalars to be applied over array: Beta0 => int, Beta1 => int
Beta0, Beta1 = 55, 0

# Generate y & t: y => numpy ndarray, t => numpy ndarray
y, t = np.linspace(1,10,100), np.linspace(1,10,100)

# Use map and a lambda function to plot the function: plt => stdout 
plt.plot(Beta2s,[*map(lambda x: rss(Beta0,Beta1,x), Beta2s)])
plt.show()
```